# tortoise svn filter logs by revisions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have been trying to figure out if I can filter the log by a range of revisions.

For example, say I have a repository that has more than 1,004 revisions. **I would like to show every revision in a range like the following:**

```
969,972,975,989,996,1000-1004
```

Rather than manually looking at each of these, I would a quick glimpse of only these revisions. They affect multiple folders within the repository and share nothing in common that would not be common with the excluded revisions between 969-1004

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case you probably would like to use regular expression (check "Use regular expression" in drop down menu):

```
969|972|975|989|996|100[0-4]
```

Also make sure that the client downloaded "enough" history (click "Next 100" or "Show All").